# How do I properly add multiple fragments to a fragment transition?

Tags: layout, view, transactions, fragment

I recently asked a question about fragments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443312/listview-not-populating-or-webview-taking-up-entire-screen):

After a lot of messing around I found what the problem was, but after more fooling around, and research (in which correct code seemed identical to mine), i cant figure out what my problem is.

After everything is created, I find that only the last fragment added to the transaction is visible. This is my code to add them:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
UrlListFragment urlfragment = new UrlListFragment();
MyWebFragment webfragment = new MyWebFragment();
trans.add(R.id.fragment_container, urlfragment, "my_url_fragment");
trans.add(R.id.fragment_container, webfragment, "my_web_fragment");
trans.commit();
```

And this is my main xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**What am I doing wrong, or what can be done so both fragments are added correctly and can be seen correctly?**

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you cant use fragments in this way you need to use just one fragment per container. It will amount to the same visual layout anyway.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
UrlListFragment urlfragment = new UrlListFragment();
MyWebFragment webfragment = new MyWebFragment();
trans.add(R.id.fragment_container1, urlfragment, "my_url_fragment");
trans.add(R.id.fragment_container2, webfragment, "my_web_fragment");
trans.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

To add multiple fragments inside one layout, you need to call `add()` and `commit()` methods for each individual fragment. But if you're adding your fragments in a loop, or for example like below:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.parentView, myFragment1, "fragment:1").commit();
manager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.parentView, myFragment2, "fragment:2").commit();
```

This might also get you into some problems. Since, the `commit()` method doesn't add the fragment immediately, you need to make sure that the previous fragment was attached from activity's `onAttachFragment()` method and then move further adding another fragment.

Comment: if I used `executePendingTransactions()` for first commit of `myFragment1`, will it helps me in the problem you mentioned?