# Adding multiple fragments in same fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

When i am adding multiple fragments to a FragmentTransaction and commiting after that only last fragment is added.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,PropertyListFragment.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .add(R.id.main_container, BlankFragment.newInstance("dfghj","fghj")).addToBackStack(null)
                        .add(R.id.main_container,PropertyListFragment.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null)
                        .add(R.id.main_container, BlankFragment.newInstance("dfghj","fghj")).addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

Backstack count is also 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use fragment in this way you need to use just one fragment per container.
check this:
[How do I properly add multiple fragments to a fragment transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444205/how-do-i-properly-add-multiple-fragments-to-a-fragment-transition)

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is right.
You can't use fragment in this way you need to use just one fragment per container but I gave you a little help here.
You need to define at the `XML` `FrameLayout` for each `Fragment` something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the `Fragment` you need to define like this.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
WebFragment webFragment = new WebFragment();
trans.add(R.id.fragment_1, listFragment, "list_fragment");
trans.add(R.id.fragment_2, webFragment, "web_fragment");
trans.commit();
```